# Inclusion of dual spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$ and $H$ be two linear or Banach spaces and $V\subset H$. Why $H^*\subset V^*$? Can I explain it with Hahn-Banach theorem?

Comment: What exactly is the meaning of $H^{*} \subset V^{*}$ here? The restriction map is not one-to-one and as sets $H^{*} \subset V^{*}$ does not hold.

Comment: I understand this the following way; take any $h^*\in H^*$. Then $h^*$ is also an element of $V^*$ with respect to the restriction. I don't see any other options.

Comment: You are only saying that there exist some map from $H^{*}$ to $V^{*}$. It is wrong to say that the inclusion holds.

Comment: A better statement.  If $V$ is a subspace of $H$, then $V^*$ is a quotient of $H^*$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly saying, we cannot say about inclusion of the dual spaces since the domains of the elements from different spaces are different.

But one thing we can say is that the restriction map from $H^*$ to $V^*$ is a surjection.

More specifically, by Hahn-Banach Theorem, if $V\subset H$, for any $f\in V^*$ there exists $F\in H^*$, an extension of $f$ ( such that $F|_V=f$). Thus, the restriction map $\psi:H^*\rightarrow V^*$ where $\psi(F)=F|_V$ is a surjection.

In this sense, $Card(V^*)\leq Card(H^*)$. Thus, if $H^*\subset V^*$ is true, then it should be $H^* = V^*$ which seems nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

If $V\subset H$, then $V$ is a subspace of $H$. If $f\in H^*$ then $f^*|_{V}$ is a linear functional on $V$. Hence $f^*\to f^*|_{V}$ gives you a map $H^*\rightarrow V^*$.

If $V\subset H$ are Banach spaces, with the norm on $V$ being the restriction of the norm on $H$, then $f^*|_{V}$ for $f^*\in H^*$ is also continuous.

Comment: But the map is not an injection so you cannot treat $H^{*}$ as  a subspace of $V^{*}$.